# Node JS does not stop server with Ctrl+C when using json-server + create-react-app

Tags: node.js, npm-scripts

I've got a sample react app I've been messing with to build out little small side projects. But I've hit a connundrum. `Ctrl+C` doesn't do anything to stop my app. I have to go through task manager manually to kill it. I've attached my package json. Is there some package or approach for this?

```
{
  "name": "practice-app",
  "description": "Sample react app to practice different designs, tools and concepts",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^1.2.2",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^1.1.0",
    "concurrently": "^3.6.0",
    "json-server": "^0.14.0",
    "react": "^16.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently \"react-scripts start\" \"json-server --watch data/db.json --port 3001\"",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3001"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe try writing an npm stop script?

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "app.js",
    "stop": "pkill --signal SIGINT myApp"
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: how would i trigger it? just `npm stop`? I'm still pretty new to the whole node ecosystem. And I'm self-learning react.

Comment: you could run it from a separate cmd window. that is pretty nasty, however im not sure why your json server isnt exiting.

Comment: My guess is that it's because I am using concurrently to run my server and then proxy my create-react-app to it. There's probably a better method using webpack configu but given that I don't have that skill set I will try this approach.

Comment: This approach doesn't work. even though I installed the pkill module.